# C Function to create BMP file header from width and height

Tags: c, image, bmp, ppm

I need help filling out a BMP file based on the width and height of an image.

What I am working with:

```
struct BMP_Header { 
    char signature[2]; 
    int size; 
    short reserved1; 
    short reserved2; 
    int offset; 
}; 

struct DIB_Header { 
    int size; 
    int width; 
    int height; 
    short planes; 
    short bit_count; 
    int compression; 
    int size_image; 
    int x_ppm; 
    int y_ppm; 
    int clr_used; 
    int clr_important; 
};
```

```
* @param header: Pointer to the destination DIB header
* @param width: Width of the image
* @param height: Height of the image
void makeBMPHeader(struct BMP_Header* header, int width, int height){
    //header->size = ???; 
    //header->offset = ???; 
}

* @param header: Pointer to the destination DIB header
* @param width: Width of the image 
* @param height: Height of the image 
void makeDIBHeader(struct DIB_Header* header, int width, int height) {
    //header->size = ???; 
    //header-> width = ???; 
    //header->height = ???; 
    //header-> bits_per_pixel = ???; 
    //header-> size_image = ???; 

}
```

I used default values for most components I just need assistance calculating the values for the components above.

Comment: I am not sure about the values you are asking about. But if you intent to write the structs directly into the file, you will run into issues with padding because some members need to be placed on certain offsets to meet alignment requirements. E.g. the field `size` is likely to be placed on offset 4 with a gap of 2 padding bytes.

Comment: Note: 1) This `BMP_Header` will not work well to write a file unless it is _packed_. 2) Use fixed width types for `BMP_Header`, `DIB_Header`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to create a .bmp file in Windows.
BITMAPINFOHEADER and BITMAPFILEHEADER structures are defined in wingdi.h (accessed from windows.h). This example creates a 24 bit RGB bitmap.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void CreateBMPFile(const char* filename, int width, int height, uint32_t color) {
    // Calculate the row size in bytes (including padding)
    int row_size = (width * 3 + 3) & ~3; // Round up to the nearest multiple of 4

    // Calculate the size of the pixel data
    int pixel_data_size = row_size * height;

    // Create and initialize the BITMAPINFOHEADER structure (DIB header)
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bih = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), width, height, 1, 24, BI_RGB, pixel_data_size, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    // Create and initialize the BITMAPFILEHEADER structure (BMP header)
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh = { 'B' + ('M' << 8), sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + pixel_data_size, 0, 0, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) };

    // Create the BMP file and write the headers
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!file) {
        return; // Error handling: Unable to create the file
    }

    // Write the BMP and DIB headers to the file
    fwrite(&bfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, file);
    fwrite(&bih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, file);

    // Write the pixel data (in BGR format) row by row
    uint8_t pixel[3] = { color & 0xFF, (color >> 8) & 0xFF, (color >> 16) & 0xFF };
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            fwrite(pixel, 3, 1, file);
        }
        // Add padding bytes (if needed) to align rows to a multiple of 4
        for (int p = 0; p < row_size - width * 3; p++) {
            uint8_t padByte = 0;
            fwrite(&padByte, 1, 1, file);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int main() {
    
    CreateBMPFile("f://output.bmp", 640, 480, 0x0000FF); // blue
    return 0;
}
```